# Pdflatex - images don't show

Tags: graphics

I am using Texmaker to create a document with pdflatex. When I add an image to it (no spaces in the path), it takes an approperiate amount of space, it shows a black border, however no image shows up. I get no message implicating a missing file.

In preamble:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{polski}
\usepackage[polish]{babel}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{authoraftertitle}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{fixme}
\usepackage{url}

\graphicspath{ {img/} }
```

Adding graphics:

```
\includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{email-invitation}
```

Result:

[image: image not showing]

What may I be doing wrong?

*Update:*

Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[draft]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics{test}
\end{document}
```

Seems plain simple...

Comment: Do you have `\documentclass[draft]{...}` ? ;-) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: `draft` means (among other things): speed things up by not including the images

Comment: I have just updated my question. Of course, my document starts with \documentclass[draft]{...} :)

Comment: @Zosia: Remove `[draft]` then

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. It helped. @DavidCarlisle - I've tried searching, but I've failed. I'll delete my question then, if I have to.

Comment: @Zosia you can delete or it will get closed as a duplicate, makes no difference really. It's always easier to search for the answer than the question when looking for duplicates:-) But it does show the importance of always including an MWE, your original version showed every line _except_ the line we needed to see:-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `draft` option to the document will prevent the inclusion of graphics via `\includegraphics`. Instead, a frame and the name of the file is displayed, in typewriter font.

This speeds up the compilation (and reduces the file size, of course, too)

In fact, it's defined in the standard classes as an option, it does not do much there:

```
\DeclareOption{draft}{\setlength\overfullrule{5pt}}
```

The 'power' of `draft` option comes in with the `graphicx` (or `graphics`) package, but it could be handed over to `varioref` and `showkeys` packages as well.

Another nice feature of the `graphicx` package is its `demo` option.

Comment: for graphics this is a duplicate (one of hundreds:-) for the standard classes `draft` works to show overfull boxes with a black rule in the right margin.